# how to apply slimSelect javascript on elements of a class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

my problem is that I want the .slim class to be applied on both elements. not just the first

```js
new SlimSelect({
  select: '.slim-select'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.27.0/slimselect.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.27.0/slimselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

<form>
  <select class="slim-select" class="info__select">
    <option value="java" data-thumbnail="'https://orig00.deviantart.net/d5fa/f/2012/088/3/0/30e49c0ab37799728a5dfc28d92bbcb7-d4ubbj8.jpg'">Java</option>
    <option value="dot-net">.NET</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option>
    <option value="c">C/C++</option>
    <option value="swift">Swift</option>
    <option value="android">Android dev</option>
    <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="python">Python</option>
    <option value="node">NodeJs</option>
    <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>

  <select class="slim-select" class="info__select">
    <option value="java" data-thumbnail="'https://orig00.deviantart.net/d5fa/f/2012/088/3/0/30e49c0ab37799728a5dfc28d92bbcb7-d4ubbj8.jpg'">Java</option>
    <option value="dot-net">.NET</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option>
    <option value="c">C/C++</option>
    <option value="swift">Swift</option>
    <option value="android">Android dev</option>
    <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="python">Python</option>
    <option value="node">NodeJs</option>
    <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

Comment: Check this https://github.com/brianvoe/slim-select/issues/111

Answer (score 4):

The [slim select](https://slimselectjs.com/) is not a jquery plugin and doesn't follow the jquery plugin rules.

The best solution will be to wrap the `new SlimSelect` in a loop:

```
$(".slim-select").each((i, e) => {
  new SlimSelect({
    select: e
  })
});
```

A quick look in the source shows that Slim Select uses `document.querySelector(info.select)` - which always returns a single element, so there's no way to get SlimSelect to apply to multiple elements with a single call.

Updated snippet:

```js
//new SlimSelect({
//  select: '.slim-select'
//})

$(".slim-select").each((i, e) => {
  new SlimSelect({
    select: e
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.27.0/slimselect.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.27.0/slimselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

<form>
  <select class="slim-select" class="info__select">
    <option value="java" data-thumbnail="'https://orig00.deviantart.net/d5fa/f/2012/088/3/0/30e49c0ab37799728a5dfc28d92bbcb7-d4ubbj8.jpg'">Java</option>
    <option value="dot-net">.NET</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option>
    <option value="c">C/C++</option>
    <option value="swift">Swift</option>
    <option value="android">Android dev</option>
    <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="python">Python</option>
    <option value="node">NodeJs</option>
    <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>

  <select class="slim-select" class="info__select">
    <option value="java" data-thumbnail="'https://orig00.deviantart.net/d5fa/f/2012/088/3/0/30e49c0ab37799728a5dfc28d92bbcb7-d4ubbj8.jpg'">Java</option>
    <option value="dot-net">.NET</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option>
    <option value="c">C/C++</option>
    <option value="swift">Swift</option>
    <option value="android">Android dev</option>
    <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="python">Python</option>
    <option value="node">NodeJs</option>
    <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
  </select>

</form>
```